# Stored Procedure If statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters, optional-parameters

I'm wanting to have a sp use a conditional parameter such as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest
(
    @param1 DATE,
    @param2 DATE,
    @param3 NVARCHAR(8) = null
)

AS

IF (@param3 = 'test1')
BEGIN
    SELECT a, SUM(b) AS SumOfB, SUM(c) AS SumOfC FROM db1 GROUP BY a
END

WITH innerQuery1 AS
(
    SELECT a, b, c FROM db2 WHERE a >=@param1 AND a <= @param2
)
    SELECT a, SUM(b) AS SumOfB, SUM(c) AS SumOfC FROM innerQuery1 GROUP BY a
```

I know this is very generic but this process works. What I'm attempting to do is put the conditional "in the middle" such as.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest
(
    @param1 DATE,
    @param2 DATE,
    @param3 NVARCHAR(8) = null
)

AS

WITH innerQuery1 AS
(
    SELECT a, b, c FROM db2 WHERE a >=@param1 AND a <= @param2
)

IF (@param3 = 'test1')
BEGIN
    SELECT a, SUM(b) AS SumOfB, SUM(c) AS SumOfC FROM db1 GROUP BY a
END

    SELECT a, SUM(b) AS SumOfB, SUM(c) AS SumOfC FROM innerQuery1 GROUP BY a
```

What happens is now it can't see innerQuery1 anymore. Can you not have a conditional in a WITH?

Any ideas as to why it doesn't work? My actual query is much longer and more nested queries. Basically trying to only have the one sp in this case and using the results from queries based on the parameter.

Thanks,

Comment: `WITH` is part of the `SELECT`.  `IF` is not.  Your second version is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: For the 1st code in your question, the second query will run even the `@param3 = 'test1'` or not, You should consider to use `ELSE`, and for the 2nd code it's incorrrect.

Comment: You can either use an explicit `IF .. BEGIN END ELSE BEGIN .. END` block (and possibly duplicate the `WITH`) or use a `WITH ... SELECT ... WHERE @param3 = 'test1' UNION ALL SELECT ... WHERE @param3 IS NULL OR @param3 <> 'test1'`. Neither approach is very elegant, but that's T-SQL for you. Consider table variables, temp tables or table-valued parameters if you feel splitting up the logic is really worthwhile.

Comment: Gordon, I was afraid of that, thanks.

Comment: Jeroen, the simplicity of my question is apparent. I was trying to avoid duplicating the inner queries. I'll look at your alternatives. Thanks

Comment: You could cobble something together using either a _table-valued function_ to handle the inner query logic or _dynamic SQL_. Performance issues may arise and, in the case of dynamic SQL, [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) opportunities.

Comment: Using Jeroen's suggestion I have switched to using a table-valued function and dynamically creating the query for Excel in VBA. There are some refresh issues I'm having but will post a separate question with the appropriate tags. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create your procedure as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest
(
    @param1 DATE,
    @param2 DATE,
    @param3 NVARCHAR(8) = null
)

AS

IF (@param3 = 'test1')
BEGIN
    SELECT a, SUM(b) AS SumOfB, SUM(c) AS SumOfC FROM db1 GROUP BY a
END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            WITH innerQuery1 AS
            (
                SELECT a, b, c FROM db2 WHERE a >=@param1 AND a <= @param2
            )
                SELECT a, SUM(b) AS SumOfB, SUM(c) AS SumOfC FROM innerQuery1 GROUP BY a;
        END
GO
```

Comment: Sami, thanks. With my simple example I can see where your code deals with it. My issue is I have 4 nested queries and was wanting to have the conditional use intermediate results. Plus the @param3 would have multiple options not a simple IF ELSE

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intent right, you might want to think of some different approach like splitting test cases into separate SPs and composing test-suites with them:

```
CREATE PROC TestSuite_CheckAggregations
    @arg,
    @param1, @param2
as
  ...
  SET @testCase = CASE @arg 
     WHEN '1' THEN 'TestCase_1_innerQuery'
     WHEN '2' THEN `TestCase_2_DirectQuery`
  END
  ...
  EXEC @testCase
    @param1, @param2
  ...
END



CREATE PROC TestCase_1_innerQuery
...

CREATE PROC TestCase_2_DirectQuery
...
```

It might be more useful to build testing system on language/framework that supports such things naturally.